# How to prevent a function which filters vector of pointers from non-const-accessing pointees?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a function, which filters a vector of pointers, returning the fitered version. By the nature of its parameter, being of type `const vector<Data*>&`, it can change `Data` structures, pointed by the pointers. Is there any way to make it unable to change `Data` through the pointers while still being able to return `vector<Data*>`, the filtered version of its argument?

Comment: You could use some pointer wrapper that will return `const&` to pointee when dereferenced and being `const`. Raw and smart pointers return mutable reference

Comment: What would you allow in your code to accomplish that? It cannot be done directly.

Comment: @black the function's parameter can be modified, source of the function also can. Even caller can. It just needs to be more or less straightforward to do (and extensible).

Answer (score 1):

You have a unary function taking:

```
(const vector<Data*>&)
```

You cannot cast the constness of the pointers inside the vector, but you can change your function's argument type.  I suggest this:

```
(const Data* const*, size_t)
```

Then, call it like this:

```
filter(vec.data(), vec.size());
```

Now your function is accepting pointers to `const Data` so cannot change them.  And the caller doesn't need to do anything very special.  You could make a wrapper if you want to keep the old calling style:

```
filter(const vector<Data*>& vec) {
  return filter(vec.data(), vec.size());
}
```

As for the return type, you can do it with `const_cast`:

```
vector<Data*> filter(const Data* const* data, size_t size) {
  vector<Data*> results;
  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < size; ++ii) {
    results.push_back(const_cast<Data*>(data[ii]));
  }
  return results;
}
```

None of this provides "perfect" safety, but then, `const` never does!

Comment: `vec.data()` would be a `Data**`, no? (or `Data * const *`, for const-qualified `vec`).

Comment: @T.C.: Thank you, I fixed that.  I've now actually compiled the code in my answer.  :)